# Port Cbor library to Beaglebone running Xinu

Tags: operating-system, porting, beagleboneblack, xinu

I have a beagle bone black running xinu and a development environment set up in a VM running on virtual box. Up till now I have been able to write Hello world shell command in Xinu. So i have a basic idea about xinu and the beagle bone. I want to port the Cbor and COAP libraries to the BBB. Do I just copy the .c and .h files in the include folder and  "make" and "make install"? or is there a more better/sophisticated way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Xinu that I am using does not have a file system. So the way to do this is to statically link the cbor library to the code.